# Multiple values for the same variable at the same date (timeseries)

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataset

I have a huge dataset spanning 2 years (almost 4M rows) which includes every day (each day has different values for the same variable; it has the exact same date with no difference in timing).

[image]

Can this be modelled in time series models (ARIMA/SAMIRA)? I only found stuff about multivariate time series forecasting datasets but unfortunately, this is not my case.

Each date has a different number of rows. I'm also not sure how much periods I have to assign.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow and congrats on your first question. Make sure you read the guidelines for posting questions. Share information that might help us help you, e.g. code, data, desired output. And remember, post your own efforts as well. Do not post screenshots. Post data.